# Can we opt out of the banner announcing Stack Overflow Podcasts?

Tags: feature-request, status-review, notifications, podcast, system-message

Every once in a while, we get a banner on top that announces Stack Overflow podcasts:

[image]

We should be able to opt out of seeing it.

If that's not possible, it should at least go away automatically.

Comment: You could adblock it... but then you're losing all of them.

Comment: It goes away as soon as you click on the “x”. But I do agree with the general spirit of this question… These site-wide banners are supposed to be reserved for important system announcements, not “we made a podcast”. Podcasts and blog posts belong in the “Community Bulletin”, just as they always have.

Comment: @CodyGray `It goes away as soon as you click on the “x”.` This is the funniest thing I have read today. I am stealing this. :D

Comment: At least it wasn't another jobs/teams ad (at least not directly)

Comment: My userscript [ReduceClutter](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReduceClutter.user.js) now blocks announcement bars containing the text "podcast".

Comment: @codyGray well that's what happens if you listen to your users ... (I mean the whole podcast / blogging thing is a result of last years developer survey ...)

Comment: I think they're trying to show off the new CEO.

Comment: Better feature request: don’t use the banner for unimportant stuff like podcasts. What should be up there right now is the announcement for the new CoC changes, particularly for people with an account.

Comment: Or the license changes, so users can agree to have their content re-licensed.

Comment: [Dismiss the “Meet The Overflow” and Podcast Episode banners network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334137/dismiss-the-meet-the-overflow-and-podcast-episode-banners-network-wide)

Comment: @CodyGray I could do without them appearing in the sidebar either.

Comment: @canon Meh. The site needs to have *some* place they can advertise their stuff. It is a business, after all. I'm okay with making some reasonable concessions, as long as they keep it in a single place and it is relatively non-intrusive.

Comment: While I dislike the notification and would prefer it gone entirely, it would be nice if - at the very least - I didn't have to close it once for every site in the network.

Comment: It's almost like announcing new episodes isn't already a built-in part of the podcast concept. If I wanted to know about new episodes I would have subscribed already.

Comment: @ivarni to unsubscribe reply unsubscribe.

Comment: @CodyGray There's the yellow side bar for `featured` meta posts. They could do that _and_ get feedback on the podcast

Comment: That's technically called the "Community Bulletin", @marcellothearcane, which is exactly where I said these belong in my [original comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390709/can-we-opt-out-of-the-banner-announcing-stack-overflow-podcasts?noredirect=1#comment736899_390709).

Comment: @CodyGray So you did. Sorry!

Comment: @CodyGray just wanted to point out that even after pressing (x) and coming back later to SO, I was greeted with the banner for a second time.

Comment: So nothing will be done about this? Not even a response?